# React Native assembleRelease app::bundleReleaseJsAndAssets never progress

Tags: gradle, react-native

I'm trying to generate release version of my app using React-native :

```
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

It's progress until app::bundleReleaseJsAndAssets gets stuck at 93% and never progress. I dont have any error on terminal.

About OS I'm on Mac OS.

Comment: Did you manage to fix it ? Im getting the same problem

Comment: Did you succeed on this? Am getting similar issue and I have no way to tell what the issue is.

Answer (score 2):

issue reported https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10078

If you are using realm, please consider that comment:

> :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets was trying to bundle the default.realm* in the root folder generated from the tests in jest... So it was hanging there.
>
> It couldn't decompile them or whatever. So i just deleted them and it worked again

I used to have realm in my project but removed it. I still had files not tracked by git, hanging around. I simply removed everything related to realm and it worked again

Answer (score -1):

If you are building the react native app in android studio and you are stuck at

app::bundleReleaseJsAndAssets never progress

It could be the issue with "CMD" in the android studio. Please Make sure you install the plugin.

I'm able to resolve the issue.